# timer control not working in ascx page

Tags: asp.net, timer, ascx

it works in aspx page but does not fire in ascx control. here is the code of ascx. Please let me know what I am missing. All the remaining controls fire but the timer does not fire in my aspx page:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID= "SM1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel id="updPnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"  ChildrenAsTriggers="TRUE">
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName="Tick"  />

</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
  <asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="timer1_tick"></asp:Timer>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTimer" runat="server" Interval="1000" Enabled="False"></asp:Label>

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 if (!SM1.IsInAsyncPostBack)
                Session["timeout"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5).ToString();
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "test", "javascript:f1();", true);
                fillQuestionsLabel();

                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }

        }
        protected void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (0 > DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now,
           DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString())))
            {
                lblTimer.Text = "Number of Minutes Left: " +
                ((Int32)DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].
                ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes).ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The timer references Timer1 but when the user control gets rendered it will have a newly assigned name because it is on a user control. Do a View Source and you will see this is the case.

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName="Tick"  />
```

Add ClientIDMode="Static" as shown below. This assumes this control is only dropped on the page one time, otherwise you should set ControlID of timer1 postback triggers to Timer1.ClientID()

```
<asp:Timer ID="timer1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="timer1_tick"></asp:Timer>
```